# How to understand this generic class defination with such type parameters constrain define in C#

Tags: c#, generics

```
class CustomClassA<T> where T : CustomClassA<T>
```

The parameter type constrain is the class itself.
I wonder why this does not lead to recursive definition?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Someone else has asked a similar question before, which already has good answers. We've therefore closed your question, and provided a link to some good pre-existing answers